# Why is "A" not used for augmented in Chord symbols?

Tags: chords, notation, chord-theory

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_names_and_symbols_%28popular_music%29#Chord_quality) it says:

> Some of the symbols used for chord quality are similar to those used
>   for interval quality:
>
> ```
>     m, or min for minor,
>     M, maj, or no symbol (see rule 2 below) for major,
>     aug for augmented,
>     dim for diminished.
> ```
>
> In addition, however,
>
> ```
>     Δ is sometimes used for major,[a] instead of the standard M, or maj,
>     − is sometimes used for minor, instead of the standard m or min,
>     +, or aug, is used for augmented (A is not used),
>     o, °, dim, is used for diminished (d is not used),
>     ø, or Ø is used for half diminished,
>     dom is used for dominant.
> ```

Is it just tradition or is there a good reason why **A** and **d** are not used for **augmented** and **diminished**?

Comment: Mainly because A and D are used for chord names; it would be confusing to use them to describe the quality of the chord as well

Comment: If that is the only reason, I use it. (I am programming something.)

Comment: If you are programming something where you expect users to type the an identifier for a chord, please do not us A or D, as these letters will then have two meanings, depending on context. It will be difficult to parse the instruction and difficult to write it, too.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is with those characters  as you can look for and display the + and ° characters in pretty much any language.

Comment: "Not *too* confusing" seems like poor reason to buck convention.  Might as well call your notes A-L instead of having sharps and flats.

Comment: I am using it internally, because there is no ° on my keyboard... Also, chord symbols are confusing: http://xenon.stanford.edu/~geksiong/code/chordcalc/chordcalc.py Btw "Not too confusing" also, because 'd' and 'A' are shorthand notations for intervals anyway: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28music%29#Shorthand_notation

Comment: Intervals, unlike chords, are not written with note names, so there's no ambiguity. You're free to do what you want, but you asked a question, and you got a clear answer: to someone who's familiar with the common terminology of music, what you're proposing would be ambiguous and confusing.

Answer (score 4):

M cannot be confused with the letter name of a note, whereas D and A can. The + is probably due to the interval (usually 5th) being larger than original by a semitone. That being the case, dim could be -, but that is sometimes used to denote minor , NNS uses it. Why o, not a clue! There isn't even an o in the word!

Answer (score 1):

Others mentioned the possible confusion with note names.  And indeed, in some German songbooks (like the 1909 "Zupfgeigenhansel") you might find Cv instead of Cdim (v for vermindert), with v not being in competition with a note name.